# Move items between two ListBoxes in ASP.Net using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, listbox, jquery-events

I want to move items between two Listboxes in ASP.Net using JQuery/Javascript and below is my code which is working perfectly.

```
function AddItems() {
    var totalItemsSelected = 0;
    var CurrentItems = 0;
    var MessageLabel = document.getElementById('<%=lblITProgrammingMessage.ClientID%>');
    var selectedOptions = jQuery('#<%=ListITProgramming.ClientID %> option:selected');

    if (selectedOptions.length == 0) {
        MessageLabel.innerHTML = "Please select skill(s) to add.";
        jQuery('#<%= lblITProgrammingMessage.ClientID %>').fadeOut(2000, function () { MessageLabel.innerHTML = ""; });
        jQuery('#<%= lblITProgrammingMessage.ClientID %>').fadeIn(500, function () { });
        return false;
    }

    jQuery('select[name$=ListMyITProgramming] > option').each(function () { CurrentItems++; });

    if (CurrentItems == 30) {
        MessageLabel.innerHTML = "Maximum limit (30) is reached. You cannot add any more skills.";
        jQuery('#<%= lblITProgrammingMessage.ClientID %>').fadeOut(2000, function () { MessageLabel.innerHTML = ""; });
        jQuery('#<%= lblITProgrammingMessage.ClientID %>').fadeIn(500, function () { });
        return false;
    }

    totalItemsSelected = CurrentItems + selectedOptions.length;

    if (totalItemsSelected > 30) {
        MessageLabel.innerHTML = "You can only select " + (30 - CurrentItems) + " item(s) more.";
        jQuery('#<%= lblITProgrammingMessage.ClientID %>').fadeOut(2000, function () { MessageLabel.innerHTML = ""; });
        jQuery('#<%= lblITProgrammingMessage.ClientID %>').fadeIn(500, function () { });
        return false;
    }

    if (selectedOptions.length == 1) {
        if (jQuery("#<%=ListMyITProgramming.ClientID %> option[value='" + selectedOptions.val() + "']").length > 0) {
        }
        else {
            jQuery('#<%=ListMyITProgramming.ClientID %>').append(jQuery(selectedOptions).clone());
        }
    }
    else if (selectedOptions.length > 1) { jQuery(selectedOptions).each(function () { if (jQuery("#<%=ListMyITProgramming.ClientID %> option[value='" + this.value + "']").length > 0) { } else { jQuery('#<%=ListMyITProgramming.ClientID %>').append(jQuery(this).clone()); } }); }
    jQuery(selectedOptions).remove();

    var hdn2 = "";
    jQuery('select[name$=ListMyITProgramming] > option').each(function () { hdn2 += jQuery(this).attr('value') + ','; });
    jQuery("#<%= listMyITProgrammingValues.ClientID %>").val(hdn2);

    return false;
}
```

But this code is limited for only one set of ListBoxes as I have hard coded the ListBox names 'ListITProgramming' and 'ListMyITProgramming'.

Can anyone make this dynamic with two parameters in existing function?

Comment: just don't hard-code things. You'll make the code easier to extend and fix both for yourself and for others

Comment: Can you please help me on the concatenation of ListBox name as I have tried with "var selectedOptions = jQuery('#<%=' + variable +' option:selected');" statement and got compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the list control in an old-fashioned HTML  tag with a known, hardcoded ID.  Example:

```
<DIV id="List1Container">
    <ASP:ListBox runat="server" id="list1"/>
</DIV>
```

In your Javascript, access the list control using the div's ID (List1Container) and jquery's ":first-child" selector.  Ta da!  You can now reference the list control without knowing its ID at all, so you don't have to do that messy code injection any more.

Bonus: Using this technique, you can now write fully static .js files, which means you can use minification and caching and greatly improve performance.